# Azure CDN [Microsoft CDN (classic)] does not honor 'preserve unmatched path: yes' in rules engines

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, azure-front-door

I have an Azure CDN - Microsoft CDN (classic) that serves multiple single-page apps via different endpoints.

I am trying to add a backend API to one of the endpoints and would like to access it in SPA using `/api` route.

I have set up the origins like this:

[image: origins screenshot]

`<my-endpoint>.azureedge.net` perfectly loads frontend-spa (the default origin group).

I want to route:

```
<my-endpoint>.azureedge.net/api/resources/my-resource
```

to this (without `/api/`):

```
<my-backend-api>.azurewebsites.net/resources/resource
```

Here is the rule I have set up to do that:

[image: rules screenshot]

But the rule actually redirects to the home page of my backend:

```
<my-backend-api>.azurewebsites.net/
```

It discards anything after `/api` in the original route even though I have set `Preserve unmatched path` to `Yes`.

What have I missed in my rule/setup?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: as it turned out, we had another rule which would override the `Preserve unmatched path` of this one.

Didn't know that even if you override the origin, other rules are still applied to the request.

The other rule was like this:

```
URL path:
  not contains: <something>
URL rewrite:
  Source pattern: /
  Destination: /
  Preserve unmatched path: No
```

Updated to this:

```
URL path:
  not contains: <something>
  & not begin with: /api       <------------------------
URL rewrite:
  Source pattern: /
  Destination: /
  Preserve unmatched path: No
```